# Maxlength attribute on textarea not working for mobile

Tags: html, validation, textarea, maxlength

How to restrict user to not enter more then maxlength in text area for mobile. I have tried maxlength attribute but its not working when user select text from predective text.

I want to limit text in text area to 300 in case of mobile for my responsive website.

I am using the Chrome and Firefox browsers on mobile

Comment: which browser are you using on mobile

Comment: chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0):

The `maxlength` attribute is not fully stable on mobile browsers. Just looking at the MDN documentation for this attribute, we find this

```
Feature      Android  Firefox Mobile (Gecko)  IE Mobile  Opera Mobile
maxlength       ?            4.0(2.0)         No Support      ?
```

Because of this volability, I would recommend using simple javascript. Something like this

```js
var textField = document.getElementById("text-field");
var charCount = document.getElementById("char-count");

textField.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (this.value.length === 299 && event.keyCode != 8) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    var length = event.keyCode != 8 ? this.value.length + 1 : this.value.length - 1;
    charCount.innerHTML = (length) + " / " + "300";
    charCount.style.color = length >= 270 ? "red" : "black";  
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text-field" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea>

<p id="char-count"></p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: Not working. user is able to enter more then 300 characters with or without selecting "predictive/auto corrections" text. Also "char-count" showing more that 300 character count.